# What does the 2 in a 2-approximation algorithm mean?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, np, approximation, polynomial-time

Does the 2 in a 2-approximation algorithm mean the solution is within 2*OPT or OPT/2?

Answer (score 17):

Typically, we use $\alpha < 1$ for maximization problems, and $\alpha > 1$ for minimization problems, where $\alpha$ is the approximation guarantee. So, a $2$-approximation algorithm returns a solution whose cost is at most twice the optimal. But as always, to be absolutely sure, go back to the definitions of the text you are reading (if a definition is not available, assume this).

Comment: [Reference](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs6820/2013fa/handouts/approx_algs.pdf)

Comment: I've definitely seen $\alpha > 1$ used for maximization problems, though personally I prefer $\alpha < 1$.